# Remote internet options

Tags: pi-3b+

I am looking to set up a RaspberryPi 3 for a trail cam and I have seen multiple option for internet access that are a little dated. **Wondering if there is anything more "up to date" that I am not aware of?** See options I have researched below. I am trying to avoid using more power than needed such as personal hotspot or the cell phone option as this will be solar powered.

1. Here is a verizon option that I could use with a data plan. [Verizon Global Modem USB730L](https://www.verizonwireless.com/internet-devices/verizon-global-modem-usb730l/#sku=sku2540056?cmp=CSE-C-HQ-NON-R-AC-NONE-NONE-2C0PX0-PX-PLA-USB730L&cvosrc=cse.google.USB730L&cvo_crid=198348032128)
2. [Huawei E3372h-153](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B013UURTL4) with Ting Sim Card.
3. This is one I found and not quite sure how to go about using and what is all involved. [Raspberry Pi 3G-4G/LTE Base Shield V2](https://sixfab.com/product/raspberry-pi-3g-4glte-base-shield-v2/)

I personally would like to use Ting only because I read you could have multiple sim cards under the same account. I live in the USA and it looks like my option 2 is for out of the states. Thanks for your time and I appreciate any personal experience any of you have had with your own set up! The initial cost isn't really the concern, its more of the reoccurring cost of the data plans.